# How to give back hdfs permission to super group?

Tags: hdfs, root, ambari, connection-refused, hdp

In order to access hdfs. I unknowing gave the following command in root user.( I had tried to resolve the following [error](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/8628/a-short-primer-on-scala-issues-and-resolutions.html) )

```
sudo su - hdfs
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/root
hdfs dfs -chown root:hdfs /user/root
exit
```

Now when I tried to access hdfs it says,

```
Call From headnode.name.com/192.168.21.110 to headnode.name.com:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

What can I do to resolve this issue.It would be great if you could explain what the command `'hdfs dfs -chown root:hdfs /user/root'`does.

I am using HDP 3.0.1.0 (Ambari)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your HDFS is down.. Check if your namenode is up.

The command `hdfs dfs -chown root:hdfs /user/root` changes the ownership of the HDFS directory `/user/root`(if it exists) to user `root` and group `hdfs`. User `hdfs` should be able to perform this command(or any command in the HDFS in the matter of fact). The "root" user of the HDFS is `hdfs`.

If you want to make user `root` an HDFS superuser, you can change the group of the root user to `hdfs` using(with user root) `usermod -g hdfs root` and then run(from user hdfs) `hdfs dfsadmin -refreshUserToGroupsMappings`. This will sync the user groups mappings in the server with the HDFS, making user `root` a superuser.